# Is there any way to merge same css classes in one?

Tags: css, optimization

Trying to optimize css code, want to turn

```
a{color:#007bff;text-decoration:none;}
a{color:#448f52;background-color:transparent}
```

Into

```
a{color:#448f52;background-color:transparent;text-decoration:none;}
```

How can i do it? Can't do it manually, code is more than 2000 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by following these two steps:

- Copy the ugly CSS code to this website [herokuapp](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/)
- Take the converted CSS to SCSS code to this website to reconvert it to pure CSS [scss-to-css](https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css)
- Take the CSS code to this website [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

This way you reformat your CSS code like the example you mentioned and you make sure your code is prefixed properly to work on all browsers such as IE and Safari

Comment: Didn't work for me, those just arrange css, but duplicates are still there

Comment: Weird, I just tested it out with lots of samples and it works perfectly, Can you please try this one [beautifytools](http://beautifytools.com/css-to-scss-converter.php) or this one [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.org/css-to-scss)

Comment: Beatifytools seems to work for me, thanks